# Automated scripts that use wordpress api

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Needed: at 0:01 check if users created any submission in my post type yesterday, and if they don't, change theirs meta.

There is no problem making such script. My issue is - how to set schedule for this script?

I know about CRON, but if i make a page with script using WP API, to use em, i need to type URL. If i get it right, CRON can't do such things, it can only run script by its real path on server, but if set path to my script, it won't use WP api, because individual my script don't know about API (isn't it?)

So, my question is how to include WP core to my script file? or how to run my script another way?

Comment: Cron can also call urls, check `wget`

Comment: try: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106857/how-make-a-php-script-run-only-with-wp-cron

Comment: would it work if i make wp_cron script scheduled once a day, and then make real CRON script, that call any page at 0:01?